# How to colorize escaped math in syntax highlighted listings?

Tags: math-mode, listings, color

my listings are syntax highlighted using `\lstset` with `escapechar=$` and `commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0.5,0}`.
Now my C-code looks like `int16_t speed; // calculated speed in $\(\frac{cm}{s}\)$` and the comment is printed green except the math-part:

[image: math no color]

How do I apply the color on the escaped math-part?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add the color specification also in the formula:

```
$\color{lstgreen}\(\frac{cm}{s}\)$
```

Complete example (please, try to include complete examples in questions):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% color definition
\definecolor{lstgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\lstset{escapechar=$, %$
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{lstgreen}\ttfamily,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
language=C,
morekeywords={int16_t}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int16_t speed; // calculated speed in $\color{lstgreen}\(\frac{cm}{s}\)$
int16_t something_else;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes there are many pieces of escaped LaTeX which should be colored (using the same color).
In this case I think using `escapebegin=\color{...}` in `\lstset` might be useful, as you do not have to repeat the color in the every piece of escaped code.

This way the [example by Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149467/34817) could be written like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% color definition
\definecolor{lstgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\lstset{escapechar=$, %$
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{lstgreen}\ttfamily,
escapebegin=\color{lstgreen},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
language=C,
morekeywords={int16_t}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int16_t speed; // calculated speed in $\(\frac{cm}{s}\)$
int16_t something_else;
\end{lstlisting}    
\end{document}
```

(the result should look the same)

This does also work for math that is escaped using `mathescape=true`.